Best method for finding centroid of 3D object?
I'm somewhat new to machine learning and want to implement a manufacturing application that finds the centroid of an irregular object so that as little material as possible is removed during processing. To summarize the process--the object (imagine something like a stick) is picked up by a robot and passed through 4 scanners. The scanners create a data cloud consisting of x, y, and z points as well as "c" points which represent the intensity of the transmission received at the scanner. The goal is to find a "centroid" based on these points. Would a method like cluster analysis be a good place to start here? I feel like it should be somewhat straightforward but I'm not completely sure how to identify the best method to apply.
